# increasing range of photo-diode detector with little voltage

Tags: photodiode, range-detector

These are the two circuits I made. The one on the left is the transmitter and the one on the right is a receiver. R4 is set to 180 ohms, R3 is set to 220 ohms, R1 is set to 9.4M and R2 is set to 4.7M. Transistor is 2N3904 and the opamp is LM324. I understand the opamp chip is an overkill for now, but I will be making multiple detectors in the future.

What I'm trying to do is make a long range transmitter/receiver. I don't know if I can optimize my circuit further or if I should just get new batteries even though they hardly have been used, or if the photo-led equipment is unsuitable.

The emitters and detectors I used are the following:

http://futurlec.com/LED/INFD5940.shtml
http://futurlec.com/LED/INF5940.shtml

Also, my receiver is powered with 4 AA cells and the transmitter is powered with a 9V cell. In the future, I want to use regulated 5V for both the transmitter and the receiver and still achieve excellent range.

What can I do to increase the range other than trying new batteries and without increasing source voltage?

[image: circuits]

Answer (score 1):

To null out the Sun, and the 120Hz, connect a Darlington collector-output to bottom of PhotoDiode. Drive the Darlingon base from an inverted (inverted by another OpAmp, pivoting around VDD/2) version of the OpAmp buffer. We want a very slow feedback, to null out the Sun.

Have this inverting OpAmp use 0.1UF Cfeedback, and 1MegOhm Rin. Tie Rin to output of first OpAmp; this new opamp+darlington nulling-loop will attempt to keep the first OpAmp at 50% of VDD.
Tie Pin+ to 10k+10K voltage divider, producing VDD/2.
Use 10Kohm from OpAmp to base of the Darlington.

This integrating-nulling-loop may let you avoid those lossy filters in front of the photodiode.

You may need to switch from NRZ bitstreams to a code that implements exactly 50% duty cycle{Miller? Manchester?}.  With that, you can speed up the nulling loop and better null more and more optical interference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Bs7z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off modulating your emitter at 38 kHz, and using a 38 kHz 3-pin detector module. This is what standard TV IR remotes do, and it makes it much less sensitive to interference such as sunlight.

Comment: What is the PIN diode? How far do you want to go between Tx and Rx?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to put a lens between the emitter and detector so that more emitter light is focussed on the diode. This, of course, will also collect ambient light and may swamp the emitter signal. In that case, do as @Ken Shirriff suggests.

Comment: In the sense of removing interfering signals, a more elaborate detector (LM567) and a different frequency than 'what standard TV IR remotes' use, might be wise.

Answer (score 0):

One simple, oft ignored improvement to such detector systems to to make them much more selective mechanically - put the detector (and possibly, but less importantly, the emitter) at the end of a long tube, black on the inside. This will, of course, require aiming it much more precisely, but it removes a lot of noise before you even get to the electronics.

A lens would be more helpful on the transmitter side of such a setup.